# Pass url with hidden parameter in url.action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way to hide parameter and pass

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("index", "mycntroller")?at='+119nuju
```

Comment: in GET query - no, in POST - no, everything you send from client to server can be viewed

Comment: is there any different way to hide and pass

Comment: @SreepathySp No, and there's no real good reason that you should want to hide information.

Comment: or is there any method to save parmeter value and get in controller ,like localstorage

Comment: @SreepathySp You can use `Session` in order to save user-specific parameter and use it later.

Comment: @SreepathySp What `119nuju` actually is? Tell us and we will try to find the most suitable way to "hide" it.

Comment: am actually trying to pass a data ,say amount securily and cant be changeable

Comment: @SreepathySp `cant be changeable` What you're looking for is impossible. You can change anything with developer tools through the browser. Make your server do the check, don't ever rely on what the browser sends.

Comment: @SreepathySp What did you do at last?

Comment: thanks all for your answer finally, i found a way and  encrypted my data

Answer (score 3):

Although you can use `POST` request or use `coockies` or request header or ... **to prevent parameters being visible at first glance**, but You should know hiding parameters will never help to increase security of your website.
Because all parameters can be monitor in tools such as `Developer Tools`, `FireBug`, ... and there **they are completely visible**.

Hiding parameters usually is for better user experience and user can't see the parameters that is meaningless for him.

So it's better don't try to hide parameters when not required.

---

In cases that the value `119nuju` is really important to you, don't pass it this way, instead consider encryption or use a key in TempData/Session for it and pass that key instead of that value. Then when the request come backs to server, retrieve the value by the key.

**Important**
If you used such ways (encryption, key, ...) it is still very important to check permission of user to see if `119nuju` or any related resource is can be accessible for this user or not to prevent [Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References)

Answer (score 0):

One way is cookie. You can hide by passing parameter value with cookies.

### Set cookie in client side.

```
function SetCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
SetCookie('at','+119nuju',1);
```

### Get cookie value on server side.

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["at"] != null // Check is exist
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("at"); //Get cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the values in header. but more coding is needed.still it s a good method. Search more about passing values in header.It s much more secure since the value is passed in the request header not in request body.It s much better than encryption also since even that method will show some random text in your url.To make it clean you can use this.